# cloud ml engine read access on bucket

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to start a Cloud ML-Engine job with my nodejs app engine project.
Since there is no library for it, I'm using the "googleapis" like this:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const params = {
    parent: 'projects/my-playground',
    requestBody: {
        jobId: 'test-job-' + Date.now(),
        trainingInput: {
            runtimeVersion: '1.6',
            jobDir: 'gs://my-ml-test-bucket',
            packageUris: ['gs://my-ml-test-bucket/MLEngine/trainer'],
            pythonModule: 'trainer.task',

            scaleTier: "CUSTOM",
            masterType: "complex_model_l",
            workerCount: "0",
            workerType: "standard",
            parameterServerCount: "0",
            parameterServerType: "standard",
            region: "europe-west1",

            args: [
                'file=gs://my-ml-test-bucket/testFile.csv',
                'threshold=0.5',
                'latent-factors=15',
                'iterations=50'
            ]
        }
    }
};
google.auth.getClient()
    .then(authClient => {
        const ML = google.ml({
            version: 'v1',
            auth: authClient
        });
        ML.projects.jobs.create(params)
    });
```

When execute the code, I get following error:

`Error creating the job. Field: package_uris Error: The provided GCS paths [gs://my-ml-test-bucket/MLEngine/trainer] cannot be read. Please make sure that the objects exist and you have read access to it.`

All files are uploaded to this directory and the `Cloud ML Service Agent` got `Storage Object Admin` rights on the bucket, but I still get this error.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have specified a directory name in the `packageUris` parameter of `trainingInput`. If you have uploaded your trainer code to Cloud Storage, you should instead pass the full path to the compressed archive file.

For example, if your training package is called `trainer.tar.gz`, you can pass in the following value: `packageUris: ['gs://my-ml-test-bucket/MLEngine/trainer.tar.gz']`.

The following link provides additional information on creating and using packages on Cloud ML Engine: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/packaging-trainer.